# Docker Windows Containers and NFS Volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have successfully created a Windows Docker Image and I can successfully run the container with docker-compose, for full functionality the application expects a folder location to exist, which is currently a NFS attached drive that contains a folder inside it that the application reads and writes to and is also used by other applications.

I have tried to find valid examples and documentation on Docker for Windows, Windows Containers and Docker Compose for Volumes that are NFS.

This is what I am currently trying

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: imageName
    ports:
      - 8085:80
    environment:
      -
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: nfs_example 
        target: C:\example
        volume:
          nocopy: true
volumes:
  nfs_example:
    driver: local
    driver_opts: 
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=\\fileserver.domain,nolock,soft,rw"
      device: ":\\Shared\\Folder"
```

The error message I get is:

```
ERROR: create service_nfs_example: options are not supported on this platform
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NFS doesn't work.I solved it using SMB on the host, then mounted that volume.

```
New-SmbGlobalMapping -RemotePath \\contosofileserver\share1 -Credential Get-Credentials -LocalPath G:
```

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: imageName
    ports:
      - 8085:80
    environment:
      -
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: G:\share1
        target: C:\inside\container
```

[This microsoft documentation on the windows containers helped me achieve this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-storage#smb-mounts)

Comment: I was going to praise you... But then I got this `error: Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 19aeae670260b165dc94ef170bc8d141a1e735d163768cc7d55846693a9fffcf: The request is not supported.` I'm desperate to make this work...